# MERGE INTO statement cannot be bound

Tags: sql, merge

I'm new to the SQL developer scene and am having trouble with the following code.  I am trying to update the [Country Name] column in table [dbo].[Country_GNI] with the [Country Name] column from [imported].[Country_Status], but the code is returning the error 'The multi-part identifier "imported.Country_Status.Country Name" could not be bound'.  I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong.  It looks as though it should work and I verified the syntax online and compared to online examples that others reported at working, but this one won't.  Can someone suggest what needs to change?  I had also read that MERGE INTO is preferred over UPDATE, though I was running into a similar problem when using UPDATE.

I have checked spelling and that the objects are listed as they exist.

```
MERGE INTO
    dbo.[Country_GNI]
USING
    import.[Country_Status]
ON
    dbo.[Country_GNI].[CountryGNI_ID] = import.[Country_Status].[CountryStatus_ID]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
        SET dbo.[Country_GNI].[Country Name] = imported.[Country_Status].[Country Name];
```

Comment: Merge may have database specific issues. What database backend are you using (Generally you should include this whenever asking about SQL code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code, I see DB called import and one called imported.  Do you have two tables with similar names?  Looks like a typo

Comment: Wow.  Ok, thank you.  In a previous life (job) we had to have 2nd eyes to verify all our work.  I don't have that option available anymore.  I don't know how many times I read this over and over.  Again, thank you.